# Characteristic of the field divides $\operatorname{dim} V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f, g: V \rightarrow V$ (with $V$ a finite vector space) be linear transformations such that $f \circ g - g \circ f = \operatorname{ld}_{V}$. Prove that the characteristic of the field divides $\operatorname{dim} V$.

I already proved that the characteristic must be a prime number, $p$. But I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: Is there a geometric property of linear maps that you know about that will let you get an equation involving $\dim V$ from this equation?

Comment: Hint: what number can you think of which is related to the diagonal of a matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Chris Sanders suggested, the trace of $\operatorname{id}_V$ is $n:=\operatorname{dim}(V)$. Since the trace of a linear function is an element in the field, and $\operatorname{tr}(f\circ g) = \operatorname{tr}(g\circ f)$ we get $0 = \operatorname{dim}(V)$, and this happens if and only if $p$ divides $\operatorname{dim}(V)$.

Comment: Thank to the three of you, just arrived at the same result and I was a bit disconcerted at first since dimV=0 but I'm glad that I got to the right result. Thanks again

Comment: Note: IMO in this you should think of $\operatorname{dim}(V)$ as $1+\dots+1$ , summing 1 $\dim(V)$ times.  For example in the field of 2 elements, $1+1=2=0$